# How to assign an object a const type while extend it from some other type or interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typeerror

Consider code like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: {x: 1},
  b: {x: 2},
};

const bx = obj.b.x; // bx is number
const nx = obj.n.x; // error as expected
```

but now I want to have more certain type info about `obj`, so i do:

```
const obj = {
  a: {x: 1},
  b: {x: 2},
} as const;

const bx = obj.b.x; // changed:  bx is 2
const nx = obj.n.x; // same:     error as expected
```

until now everythink is ok, but now I need to restrict other team members to patch/add values to `obj` in specific general-shape, so:

```
type GeneralTypeToFollow = { [k in string]: {x: number} }

const obj: GeneralTypeToFollow = {
  a: {x: 1},
  b: {x: 2},
  
  wrong: 'wrong type', // error as expected
} as const;


const bx = obj.b.x; // changed: bx downgraded to number
const nx = obj.n.x; // changed: nx is number (no error at all)
```

Restriction now works, but `bx` and `nx` has lost correct types.

So the expected behavior is:

```
const bx = obj.b.x; // bx is 2
const nx = obj.n.x; // error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to have a generic function. This function can constrain the passed object to `GeneralTypeToFollow` and also return the the type of the object literal.

```
type GeneralTypeToFollow<N extends number> = { [k in string]: { x: N } }

function makeObj<
  T extends GeneralTypeToFollow<N>,
  N extends number
>(obj: T): T {
    return obj
}

const obj = makeObj({
  a: { x: 1 },
  b: { x: 2 },
});


const bx = obj.b.x; // 2
const nx = obj.n.x; // error
```

By using the additional generic type `N` to represent the numbers, we can also get rid of `as const`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=29&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBDANgFXBDB7AYrmmrgO4A8AclBAB7AIAmAzlPAK4C2ARsgHxQAvFADeUANoBrKAEt4UZsCRyA5gF0AXKKi0t1AL5R9AKGMAzdvADGwGbnmcUkiAHluAK3LGoUDDXpMrHCIqJjYeITEZFR8ADTeUNR0DPAsbFy8SMZ8ABS4HloYAJSFogk%20SBDA7Ejy%20e7GJsZW9opQ9UJQjs5u7jkiCShaYrpQAIxG8T7cwzpaAEyTjUUA3KbNrcBQ3LSd9QB03Pu0K1AA9GdQ8xvwbfC7wgfwx6cXNEhIuEhAA)

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. I may convert and use it like an IIFE. Also at first I felt bad about creating an object at runtime, but than I remembered that JS does not compile :)

Comment: these type gynmastics are so complex and bloated that, if this is truly the only way to achieve this, I think it would be better to just throw ts out the window and either use traditional js or `any`, and this would substantially clean up the code by dramatically simplifying it